# Attempting to redirect users to home page after wordpress login

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, authentication

As the title says, I am trying to redirect users, after they log in, back to the homepage. Here is the function I have in functions.php:

```
function redirect_to_front_page() {
wp_redirect( get_option('home') );
}

add_action('wp_login', 'redirect_to_front_page');
```

For some reason I just get redirected to the login form.

Sorry for the simple question, still quite new to wordpress

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
function redirect_to_front_page($redirect_to, $request, $user) {
    return (is_array($user->roles) && in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) ? admin_url() : site_url();
} 
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_to_front_page', 10, 3);
```

Note that it's making sure it's not an administrator before redirecting the user.